# Sendmail is periodically sending emails

Tags: linux, sendmail, smtp

The exchange mail server showed that there is a server is sending emails with 17000+ emails in queue. After blocking the server from sending emails, we investigated the outgoing traffic using Wireshark (filter is set to `smtp`) and there is some traffic on port 25 trying to come out from the server. When a new filtered traffic arrived, `netstat -atnp` showed that `sendmail` is sending emails. What causes `sendmail` to send emails like this? Be advised that there are no `crontabs` running.

Comment: if you are wise to wireshark you could have investigated the content of the emails.

Comment: There are no emails being sent, the system admins blocked the server from sending emails, but sendmail kept sending SMTP commands like `EHLO` and `STARTTLS`

Comment: see the queue, clean it, figure out if they only blocked sending and not receiving and try to use common sense.

Answer (score 6):

`sendmail` would not send mail by itself. You either have another program running that is using `sendmail` to send out mail, or you have `sendmail` listening on a port and relaying mail to outside.

Use `mailq` to see if you have any mail pending in the queue.

Look at `/var/log/maillog` to see what log messages are written by `sendmail`

Try `netstat -nlatup|grep sendmail` to see which ports `sendmail` is listening on.